# Will using ubuntu from a external hdd give me same performance as using ubuntu from internal hard drive?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, hard-drive, performance, external-hdd

> I have a potato laptop and I intend to use blender from ubuntu in
> order to get somewhat better performance for rendering and modelling
> and other stuff.
>
> I also need windows because I use davinci resolve (free version)
> for video editing and free version have problem with encoding H264,also I am starting to hate windows. My stupid task manager keeps showing high disk usage.
>
> So I thought about installing ubuntu on an external hdd and use it for blender because I know its awesome, I saw some benchmark results and there was 30% boost
> , but I am concerned about performance because if I won't get similar kind of performance  boost than sadly I would have to work as a slave under windows and I would never be able to become truly free.

So my question is

**Will I get same kind of performance with installing ubuntu on external hdd as i will get with internal Hdd ?? Also what if I use ssd**

I need it specifically for blender and i would be happy with that

Or should i dual boot? hmmmmmmmmmmmm........

I have 8 Gigs of ram, i5 7th gen 2.5ghz, nvidia 940mx 2gb and intel graphics 4gb

Thanks in advance for answering (arigato)

Comment: I had an old SSD and connected it with a USB to SATA adapter. I was surprised how fast it was, faster than HDD and almost as fast as internal SSD. I previously always had full installs on flash drives and they were typically slow loading & writing. But adapter would not work with HDD. Not enough power from USB port. If you want HDD, use one that has separate power. But I suggest an SSD.

Comment: My experience is that an SSD connected via an eSATA or USB 3 adpater or box can be a very good alternative to dual booiing in the internal drive. If you don't want to touch the internal drive, you can unplug it before you start installing Ubuntu into the external drive. But if it is OK to get grub into the internal drive and select operating system that way.

Comment: @sudodus what do you mean by unplug internal drive (I am on laptop)

Comment: The laptops that I know are designed so that it is possible to unplug the internal drive in order to replace a damaged drive or replace it with a 'bigger' one (that can store more data). Sometimes it is very easy, sometimes it is not that easy. Chances are that you can do it with a manual via the internet for your computer brand name and model and a small screwdriver. I know that some netbooks have SSDs soldered to the mainboard, but those are corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

[SATA 3.0 has 6.0Gb/s transfer speeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_revision_3.0_(6_Gbit/s,_600_MB/s,_Serial_ATA-600)). The Wikipedia page also shows [comparisons to other buses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Comparison_to_other_interfaces) (ie: SATA vs USB).  Thunderbolt 2/3 and USB 3.1/3.2 appear faster, but I believe USB is half duplex, while SATA is full.  Additionally, it seems the packets, or how USB communicates, is less efficient for disks than those of a SATA connection.

The SSD is capable of using multiple PCI lanes to connect, and I think the PCI bus is closer to the CPU or has higher priority, though I'm having a hard time finding any evidence to support this.

Reasons why to use SATA over USB are discussed in more detail [in this post](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/798860-is-this-scary-sata3-vs-usb-30/?do=findComment&comment=10050693).

---

Alongside these reasons, you could use your external hdd to store non-system files, such as media or other data you'd want to carry over to your next machine.  Keep all of the system data on the internal HDD and when you switch computers, all of your personal data and files can be easily taken with you.

Comment: when you say "use your external hdd to store non- system files and just carry media file" what do you mean? Is that something I have to do during installation of ubuntu on external hdd or do you mean that just carry blender files i want to edit in external hdd so then I won't have to worry about data transfer.

Comment: Yes, for example, you could create a partition on the external HDD, and have the system mount it as `/user/`.  When you switch machines, you do the same, but be sure to not format the partition, just mount it.  You could alternatively create a partition and mount it somewhere like `/mnt/data`, which could have directories such as `Pictures/` or `Videos/`, etc.